# Create scoped variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In C# braces can be used to explicitly create a local scope for variables:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    {
        // bool (System.Boolean)
        bool min = false;
        bool max = true;
        // Do something with min/max as bool
    }

    {
        // short (System.Int16)
        short min = short.MinValue;
        short max = short.MaxValue;
        // Do something with min/max as short
    }
}
```

Is it possible to artificially create local scope like this in VB.NET?

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend this in C# but you could do something line If true Then ... End If. But that's a bit naff!

Comment: @SteveHarris: Perhaps, but the question is "can you", not "should you"! Just tried that `If True Then...End If` trick and it works (thanks), but agree its a bit naff :o)

Comment: If you want something *fancy* (let's say): `With Nothing Dim a As Boolean = True End With With Nothing Dim a As String = "Not true" End With`. Or something along this line. Or `With Me` :)

Comment: I might prefer `Do ... While False` as an analog to the code I use in a C or C++ macro to prevent issues with messing with surrounding code, if it's really necessary.

Comment: @Craig: `Do ... While False` doesn't compile for me. Did you mean `Do ... Loop Until True`?

Comment: @AlainD That would be fine.  Mine might be supposed to be `... Loop While False`, I didn't actually test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to use one of the pre-defined block constructs (`Using`, `Try`, `While`, `If`, etc.) to create a block scope in VB.NET.

An obvious workaround would be to create a block which is executed exactly once (`If True Then`, `For i = 1 To 1`, `Try ... Finally`), but this might make your code harder to read. *Usually*, such blocks are a good candidate for refactoring into a separate method anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most innocuous way would be to use a `With` block:

```
    With True|Nothing|0|etc
        Dim test As String = "1"
    End With

    With True|Nothing|0|etc
        Dim test As String = "1"
    End With
```

This compiles fine but I'm a little mystified about the reason(s) to do something like this.